# how to provide testing data while publishing app to windows phone store

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to publish an application to Windows Phone Store. The application requires latitude and longitude for loading the data, This application will not work for all the locations. So how do I provide test data for application submission process to Windows Phone Store..

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When submitting an app Under the Upload and Describe Your XAP Just click on the More XAP options, select the Certification notes. Their we can write the note.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you application wont work for everyone who downloads the application from the appstore. I would recommend the following options:

1) Set up a default location when your application starts and and location is turned off, or doesn't fall within the bounding box of your location.

2) You must let know the user that the application is working only in certain areas ( name those areas, and they can test it that way with emulator)

3) Allow the user to select from a list of cities or locations where the application is working.

4) If the application is not meant for commercial purposes then just pass the xap file to your friends or who ever, and they can deploy it themselves.

I hope this helps.